# self.votable not assigning values to the votable instance in a model callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a **Post** model that has a polymorphic association with a **Vote** model:

**post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :total_votes

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :votes, :as => :votable, :dependent => :destroy 
end
```

**vote.rb**

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :votable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user

  before_create :update_total

  protected

  def update_total
    self.votable.total_votes ||= 0
    self.votable.total_votes += self.polarity
  end
end
```

As you can see in **vote.rb** I want to accomplish the following:

Each time an instance of **Vote** is created, I want to update the `total_votes` column of the `votable` model instance (in this case an instance of **Post**).

But nothing happens, when I create a vote for a post with `post.votes.create(:polarity => 1)`, the `total_votes` column of the post still being `nil`.

Any suggestions to fix this?

**EDIT:**

This didn't work either:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :votable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user

  before_create :update_total

  protected

  def update_total
    self.votable.total_votes ||= 0
    self.votable.total_votes += self.polarity
    self.votable.save!
  end
end
```

**schema.rb:**

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "comments_count", :default => 0, :null => false
    t.integer  "total_votes"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `Vote` object, the `Post` object already exists. You update it, but you don't save it. Try with the following code:

```
def update_total
  self.votable.total_votes ||= 0
  self.votable.total_votes += self.polarity
  self.votable.save!
end
```

Comment: Thanks that made sense but it didn't help. Please look at my **EDIT**

Comment: @user734290 Can you check that the `update_total` method is called (with a debug message) ?

Comment: Never mind, I think it was working. Thanks a lot! For some reason the total votes didn't show if I did this: `post = Post.find_by_id(29)` in the terminal but did when I did this: `post = Post.find_by_id(29)` again. Any idea of why?